# URL rewriting of WooCommerce API V2 URLs in WordPress does not work

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I have a WordPress site setup with WooCommerce.
The site is hosted on a Nginx server with PHP 7.2.

The problem I face is that external API calls to the site do not work.

For example, a call to the WC API V2 as:
https://www.custommadewraps.com/wc-api/v2/orders?consumer_secret=cs_&consumer_key=ck_

Reports:

```
{"errors":[{"code":"woocommerce_api_authentication_error","message":"Consumer key 
is missing."}]}
```

But the consumer key is there in the query string (`consumer_key=ck_`).

The WC API calls are rewritten by WordPress as:

```
^wc-api/v([1-3]{1})(.*)?    
index.php?wc-api-version=$matches[1]&wc-api-route=$matches[2]
```

And a call to the rewritten URL: https://www.custommadewraps.com/index.php?wc-api-version=2&wc-api-route=/orders?&consumer_secret=cs_&consumer_key=ck_

gives the expected response:

```
{"errors":[{"code":"woocommerce_api_authentication_error","message":"Consumer key 
is invalid."}]}
```

It detects the consumer_key and reports that it is valid.

I am out of ideas for debugging so that is why I reach out to you guys (and girls).

What I have noticed is that the content of the `$_GET` variable is different in both cases.

empty

```
array(0) {
}
```

vs:

```
array(4) {
  ["wc-api-version"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["wc-api-route"]=>
  string(8) "/orders?"
  ["consumer_secret"]=>
  string(3) "cs_"
  ["consumer_key"]=>
  string(3) "ck_"
}
```

All ideas are welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Pieter

Answer (score 0):

https://htaccess.madewithlove.be

[image]
    The new url is https://www.custommadewraps.com/index.php?wc-api-version=2%26wc-api-route=/orders

Thats why *Consumer key is missing*

Comment: Hi Oleksii, thanks for the reply but the this is not related to htaccess. It is a Nginx server (not Apache). The URL rewriting is done by WordPress itself so the rule needs to be seen as a PHP regex. Anyhow, I do expect content in the $_GET variable which is not there...